# Optimizing of writing images to memory

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, nvidia

I am currently working on a project were part of the task is to save images to the disk as fast as possible. I'm working on a Nvidia Jetson TX1 board with a SSD drive while the camera is connected via USB3. For image processing i'm using openCV written in c++. Each image is roughly 1.5Mb and so far I've used openCV's method imwrite for the task. This leads to about 8Fps when recording. I'm wondering how can I improve these results. Using videoWriter class is faster compare to imwrite? maybe creating a queue of images and a parallel thread for writing? any other methods?

Thanks,
Yuval

Comment: What OS are you using? How is the SSD attached? Are your images really 1.5Mbits? Or actually 1.5MBytes? How long do you need to record for? What format do you need to write - JPEG, PNG?

Comment: Are you looking to save uncompressed BMP files? Compressed jpeg? Lossless png?

Comment: Do you do your processing on the acquiring thread? What frame rate can you achieve with no processing or saving? What about just with acquiring and processing?

Comment: I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 and 1T GB SSD connected via USB3. I need to save the RAW images (mosaiced - 1088x2048 - 1 channel, unsigned char). Since this is the RAW data I can't use compression and so far I've used lossless PNG with openCV "imwrite" . For a different project I tried saving images into a binary file but didn't get almost any speed-up compare to imwrite. The recording time can be limited to an extent (I know that AVI is limited to 2GB so I can create a new file when this limit is reached)